# Noisy lines in all scenes for Landsat 7?

Tags: landsat, image, imagery, satellite, landsat-7

I'm seeing patterned lines in all Landsat 7 images that clearly are image artifacts.  There are lines that jet in from the edges (the center looks better)  Does anyone know what it is and if there are certain processing levels that they are absent from?

This is the original resolution scene link:
[image]

And here is a smaller version with arrows that mark the lines in the image.
[image: with lines highlighted]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read about the **Landsat 7 ETM+ SLC-off data**

This refers to all Landsat 7 images collected after May 31, 2003, when the Scan Line Corrector (SLC) failed. These products have data gaps, but are still useful and maintain the same radiometric and geometric corrections as data collected prior to the SLC failure.

https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-7?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con

Now if you have ERDAS you can get this corrected using focal analysis:

https://youtu.be/5mvrCxcoksg

https://youtu.be/qMIUcmKI3o4